# Creating new JS file from the selected code

Tags: webstorm

Is there a way in Webstorm to quickly create a new file from the selection?

For example, lets say I am working in **product.js** on a Product class and realize I also need a new Manager class. In C# via Resharper, I can write the new class right there in **product.js**, then select it and ask Resharper to move it to its own file. Resharper would create a new file and move the code there.

In WebStorm I need to do these steps manually:

1. Create new file
2. Write code there (or cut-paste it if I already wrote it else wrote it elsewhere)
3. Add a  reference to my html.

Is there a way to speed up that process in Webstorm?

Answer (score 1):

this option is only available for javascript embedded in HTML: Refactor/Extract/Extract Include File...

Comment: That's nice, I guess, but I would like this option in JS files. I hardly write JS code in HTML.